# Using Ajax and PHP to update shopping cart

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am attemtping to use Ajax and PHP to create a shopping cart. At the moment I console.log and can see that the correct product ID is being selected when I click 'add cart' but nothing happens in my PHP when I try and var dump the POST data that should be sent. I need to be able to get that product ID in my PHP, search the database for the product and then add to the basket.

PHP

```
<?php
session_start();

include('classes/class-database-functions.php');

$database = new Database_Functions();

if($_POST) {

    var_dump($_POST);

}
?>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
        $(".form-item").submit(function(e){
            var form_data = $(this).serialize();
            var button_content = $(this).find('button[type=submit]');
            button_content.html('Adding...'); //Loading button text 

            $.ajax({ //make ajax request to cart_process.php
                url: "cart_process.php",
                type: "POST",
                dataType:"json", //expect json value from server
                data: form_data
            }).done(function(data){ //on Ajax success
                $("#cart-info").html(data.items); //total items in cart-info element
                button_content.html('Add to Cart'); //reset button text to original text
                alert("Item added to Cart!"); //alert user
                if($(".shopping-cart-box").css("display") == "block"){ //if cart box is still visible
                    $(".cart-box").trigger( "click" ); //trigger click to update the cart box.
                }
            })
            e.preventDefault();
        });
});
```

Comment: did you check in network tab whether you ajax sent or not?

Comment: try to do `console.log(form_data)` underneath `var form_data = $(this).serialize();` and look in the console to see if you have data inside of the `form_data` string. If not try to add `e.preventDefault();` underneath `$(".form-item").submit(function(e){`

Comment: Is it possible, that your PHP code is not working properly? Maybe it crashes in the include or something. Check this by accessing the apache error log. Check also if your AJAX is sent to the server with chrome network tab (also mentioned above) and/or apache access log. You can also do a echo at the start of your script to see if it is called (maybe routing problem?) - this will also crash your response since it is not JSON anymore.